# VBA: How to filter a table by a list

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to filter a table (first pic) by a list of values (second pic)

First Pic, Column C is used to filter the values:

[image]

Second Pic:

[image]

I tried the following code but it gives me an error

```
Sub FilterByList()

Dim count As Integer
Dim list As Variant

Worksheets("A").Activate

'The debugger highlights this next line of code when throwing up the error
count = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A1", Range("A1").End(x1Down)))

list = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(count, 1)).Value
list = Application.Transpose(list)
list = Join(list, ",")
list = Split(list, ",")

Worksheets("B").Activate
ActiveSheet.Range("A2").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria:=list, Operator:=xlFilterValues

End Sub
```

[image]

I'm not sure whats wrong with my code. But I can also accept other VBA methods to filter a table by a dynamic range.

Comment: `xlFilterValues` is another typo. It's the letter `l` as in `llama`, not the number `1`. Also please specify what line throws the error

Comment: same error still comes up after fixing the typo, i've added a comment in the code that specifies the line that throws the error

Comment: Parenthesis in the wrong place and another typo, should be `l` instead of `1` again.

Comment: [Better way to find the last row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-in-finding-last-used-cell-in-excel-with-vba)